# Cannot get Angularjs directive to show in view

Tags: angularjs

Please believe me I've tried it all.  But no matter what I do, I cannot get the header directive I've made  to show up when I render main.html. What am I missing.  Any help much appreciated!
Thanks

Here is my header.component.js

```
angular.
    module('header')
    .directive('header', function () {
        return {
             restrict: 'E',
             templateURL : 'app/Shared/header.html',
        }
  
    });
```

header.module.js

```
angular.module('header', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

header.html
<div>
    <md-menu-bar>
        <md-menu>
            <md-button ng-click="vm.openMenu($mdMenu, $event)">
                Joe Porter
            </md-button>
            <md-menu-content>
                <md-menu-item>
                    <md-button>
                        Logout
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
            </md-menu-content>
        </md-menu>
    </md-menu-bar>   
</div>
```

main.html

```
<div header></div header>
<div class="container ">
    <center>
        <h1>
```

main.module.js

```
angular.module('main', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'header']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only activate your `header` via `restrict: 'E'` which is short for `Element` which means it only runs as you write as element `<header />`. So in in order to work with attribute you just simply add more `A` which is attribute:

```
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that did not made a difference.  I have no console errors, but the name doesn't show up in the header

Comment: I suspect there something wrong with above template: `<div header></div header>`. You can write either `<div header />`. I also notice if you set it as `E`, you will consume like `<header />` but it could be have collision with the native header tag so if you're keen to as element, should rename then such as `<your-header />` with `.directive('yourHeader',`